# Does C++ have existing method to check if an object is a derived-typed object?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Does C++ have existing method to check if an object is a derived-typed object? For example,

```
class A
{};

class B : public A
{};

A* p;
```

And check if `p` points to `B`.

Comment: ...you mean like [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)?

Comment: `std::is_base_of` lets you test it at compile time.

Comment: @jaggedSpire: Which should fail since the type is not polymorphic.

Comment: @doug: Which is a compile time property of `A` with respect to `B` and not of `p`.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: It's doable on an object. See my answer.

Comment: @doug: You do not test wether an `A*` actually points to a `B`.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: You can't test whether a `double *` actually points to a double either. C++ is a strongly typed language. In template code the question of whether a pointer is typed to point to a derived object that has a specific base class does sometimes arise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the class is polymorphic (i.e., has at least one virtual member function), you can use `dynamic_cast` or `typeid`.

Otherwise, no. Keeping track of an object's dynamic type has a cost, and the language was designed to avoid pessimizing code that has no need for it.

Comment: No!  You absolutely can determine this w/o requiring polymorphic behavior.

Comment: Revision: You can only test if a pointed to object has, or does not have, a specific base class if it is non-polymorphic.

Answer (score 5):

> And check if `p` points to `B`.

You can use `dynamic_cast` for that, if there is at least one `virtual` member function in the class. It is common to make the destructor `virtual`.

```
class A
{
   virtual ~A() {}
};
```

and then,

```
B* bPtr = dynamic_cast<B*>(p);
if ( bPtr )
{
   // Use the pointer
}
```

Comment: You can use `std::is_base_of` to determine this at compile time without the need for polymorphism. See my answer.

Comment: @doug, That's now what the OP wants. He has a pointer of base class type and wants to determine whether it really points to a derived class.

Comment: @R Sahu: My answer demonstrates using this with a pointer to a class object. Did you read the code in the answer? Sorry, the description wasn't clear. Fixed.

Comment: @doug, you are mistaken. You cannot determine that an `A*` really points to a `B` object at compile time. Yes, I did read your answer. I even built and ran it.

Comment: @R Sahu: I agree that if the object is polymorphic that you can't determine that at compile time but the OP's example isn't polymorphic.

Comment: @doug, true. It still does not mean that you can do that at compile time using `std::is_base_of`.

Answer (score 1):

> Does C++ have existing method to check if an object is a derived-typed object?

There are actually two ways to achieve this:

```
A* p = new B(); 
B* pB = static_cast<B*>(p); // Checks if B is related to A in an inheritance 
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    hierarchy. Fails to compile if not.
```

---

```
A* pA = new B();
B* pB = dynamic_cast<B*>(pA); // Checks if pA actually points to an instance of B
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     at runtime, and returns nullptr if not
if(pB) {
  // do stuff with B
}
```

The latter example requires you have a `virtual` base class:

```
class A { 
public:
    virtual ~A() {} // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
};
```

Comment: What are you expected to do with the allocated object, especially if it is not polymorphic? I'd suggest you remove your first way, it's way to dubious.

Comment: @SergeyA Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

If the object in question is not a polymorphic class it is possible to determine whether a class object pointed to has a specific base class at compile time. This sometimes occurs in template code where different base classes are possible.

You use std::is_base_of as follows: Note that you must also use std::remove_reference since *p is an lvalue and decltype() produces a reference.

```
#include  <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class A {};
class B : public A{};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    A* pa=&a;
    B* pb=&b;
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<A, B>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<B, A>::value << "\n";  // false
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<A, std::remove_reference<decltype(*pb)>::type>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<B, std::remove_reference<decltype(*pa)>::type>::value << "\n";  // false
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot do at compile time using `std::is_base_of` what the OP wants to.

Comment: @R Sahu: The OP's question seemed about a non polymorphic class. You can test if a pointer to an instance has a specific base class. I don't know of any way to test whether it is derived from an unspecified class.

Comment: @R Sahu: I suspect the OP was interested in polymorphic objects and I was thinking of template code where sometimes you want to test what the base class is amongst a set of possibilities.  I've seen that done but it's been a while. Most template stuff isn't polymorphic. I didn't see a virtual method so just assumed he was talking about non-polymorphic base class testing.

Comment: Now that you know, you probably should delete your answer. It doesn't really provide a solution to the OP.

Comment: @R Sahu: I'm inclined to agree. I clarified the answer but based on his question and tags  c++ not c++11 I am now pretty certain non-polymorphic base class testing wasn't what the OP had in mind. The question itself only makes sense when using templates if limited to non-polymorphic cases as it's the only time you aren't certain about the base class. I've been around templates too long.

Comment: I clarified the answer as only applying to non-polymorphic cases when testing against a specific base class. While this almost certainly does not apply to the OP there was enough ambiguity in his question that others have also remarked about the non-polymorphic case so it may come up in searches by others. And it does apply to non-polymorphic templated classes when you want to test against one or more specific base classes.